# SvelteKit $app cannot be found in svelte.config.js

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I installed a fresh SvelteKit per the documentation and receive this error if I attempt to use `$app` in the svelte config.

> Error in svelte.config.js

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '$app' imported from /Users/username/projects/my-app/svelte.config.js

The code looks like -

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { dev } from '$app/env';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            base: dev ? '' : '/CapitalBikesProject'
        },

        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte'
    }
};

export default config;
```

How do I access dev mode inside the config javascript file? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. The solution is this, you cannot use the `$app` inside the config file if you would ever need the environment you need, you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` which returns strings `production` and `development`

## UPDATE

With Sveltekit PR merged with [5602](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/5602) and mentioned in changelog [100-next384](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/kit/CHANGELOG.md#100-next384=)

If you still would like to use this trick on the `svelte.config.js` then consider updating your dev script from `"dev": "vite dev",` to `"dev": "NODE_ENV=development vite dev",`.

Change your `svelte.config.js` to this.

```js
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : '/CapitalBikesProject'
        },

        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte'
    }
};

export default config;
```